# New Class Name "Song" Extends Laravel 5 Model Class not found

Tags: class, laravel, model, eloquent, extends

I have created new Class Called "song".

Location of the class app/ClassName , so its app/songs.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
class Song extends Eloquent {
//put your code here
}
```

My Route:

```
Route::get('/','SongsController@index');
```

My SongsController.php location: app/Http/controller/SongsController.php

Wanting to correspond my database table called "songs".

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Song;

class SongsController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
$songs = Song::get();

return view('pages.songsList',compact('songs'));
}
```

Now with all these code, I get a simple error says as below,

```
FatalErrorException in SongsController.php line 19:
Class 'App\Song' not found
```

If I use without adding class "Song" model works fine. The code is as below

```
DB::table('songs)->get();
```

Thanks in Advance, Sorry I am new to Lavaral 5.

Comment: Class is called `song` and file is called `songs`. They need to match. It should be `Song.php`

Comment: Hi @BenSwinburne, Thanks for instant answer. Yes As soon as I match class name and file name the error has vanish.

Comment: Can you explain why do we need to match class and file name as same.

Comment: I've explained in an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class is called `Song` and the file is called `songs.php`. You need to name the file `Song.php` in order for it to be found.

Composer generates a [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) compatible autoloader.

You'll notice in your composer.json file you have a section like this

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

This tells the Autoloader that anything in the `App` namespace should be found within the `app` directory.

When classes are called, any registered autoloaders attempt to load the class file. This means that `App\Song` looks for `app/Song.php` unless you specify otherwise.

From the specification

> When loading a file that corresponds to a fully qualified class name ...
>
> A contiguous series of one or more leading namespace and sub-namespace names, not including the leading namespace separator, in the fully qualified class name (a "namespace prefix") corresponds to at least one "base directory".
>
> The contiguous sub-namespace names after the "namespace prefix" correspond to a subdirectory within a "base directory", in which the namespace separators represent directory separators. The subdirectory name MUST match the case of the sub-namespace names.
>
> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command :

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

**EDIT :** this command update the autoloader with the new classes.
More info : https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.